# Drawing concentric circles that correspond to free space loss formula?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, raster-calculator

I want to be able to draw a circle with 50km radius and then fill the circle with values corresponding to the free space loss formula below:

FSPL(db)=20 log<sub>10</sub>(d)+20log<sub>10</sub>(f)+32.44

for example:
[image]

a circle of 50km around the "west Myara site" and then for every pixel(I guess) I would like to know its corresponding FSPL value and have it colored accordingly.

would I have to convert the polygon to a raster and then use the raster calculator to produce the values of each cell/pixel? if thats the case I would need to find the distance of the pixel/cell from the center point (in this case "west of Myara site" point) and how would I do that ?

Comment: What f and d represent ?

Comment: @nickves F=frequency(in MHz)and D=distance(in Km), so distance would be the distance between the cell and the centre point "West Myara..." and Frequency would be any of these 5,6GHz,8GHz,11GHz, and so on(any Microwave tech)

Comment: How are you going to specify freq? How are they displayed when there are multiples?

Comment: I will perform the analysis for each of those frequencies. ultimately I would like to produce such circles for each of our sites(1000's) for each frequency

Comment: You have a QGIS tag but make no mention of what you have tried to do with that software to answer your question prior to posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach would be:

1. Rasterize the point "west Myara site"
2. Generate the buffer (there are plenty of tools for buffering raster, look for "raster distance" or "proximity". QGIS has this algorithm)
3. Use raster calculator using the formula, f stands for frequency of the wave (a constant value) and d will be buffer layer you calculated previously.

Comment: Caiohamamura, im trying to convert the vector points to rasters and im not having any luck, all I get is a blank raster file, I have no idea what im doing at this point :(

Comment: That's tricky, I think there's some bug with gdal_rasterize. Here I need to use gdal_rasterize with -te to specify extents and -tr to specify resolution, then it will be filled with 0. Then you run gdal_rasterize again without setting anything, just the -a field to the same output as previous

Comment: You may need to set the -a_srs too

Comment: what values should I use for -te and -tr and in regards to -a the rasterize dialog box wont let me choose the attribute field its locked and greyed out.

is -a_srs different from -a followed by attribut column name ?

Comment: Iv'e found an easier solution, it's a problem of extents when you have only one point the rasterize won't know what will be the extent of the new raster, so add two dummy points surrounding the point of interest and attribute a value of 0 to the field you set in -a. Then rasterize should work.

Comment: ok, did that and now the raster I get on the point is a big square. gonna attempt the proximity tool on that raster now. not sure how to use it though. 

do i set the values field to 1 or 0 ?
do i set max dist to 50000(should equal 50Km in my project CRS)

Comment: Depend on what EPSG you are using. If it's a latlong then it should be something like 0.5 degrees (1 degree ~= 110 km). If it is UTM then it should be 50000.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, the raster of the point results in a black square with only 2 values "nan" and "0". 

as I said earlier in QGIS the rasterize tool wont let me choose an attribute field, I have to manually edit the command at the bottom. I then set the raster resolution to H:30 and V:30 then in the code I add the -a ID, so the command is this 

gdal_rasterize -a ID -tr 30.0 30.0 -l West_Myara "C:/Users/LazarusA/Desktop/mining site/West_Myara.shp" "C:/Users/LazarusA/Desktop/mining site/buffer/West_Myara_rast.tif"

Comment: ID can't be used as attribute for rasterize, create a new field assign 1 to point of interest and 0 to other points then run `gdal_rasterize -a new_field -tr 30.0 30.0 -l West_Myara "C:/Users/LazarusA/Desktop/mining site/West_Myara.shp" "C:/Users/LazarusA/Desktop/mining site/buffer/West_Myara_rast.tif"`.

Be careful with projection, if you are using latlong 30 will be 30 degrees (~330 km)!

Comment: fixed the problem with the attribute field, turns out the field has to be interger with length of 2.

Comment: projection is UTM, im now at the stage where I can use the raster calculator. 
</n>
original formula is 
FSPL(db)=20 log10(d)+20log10(f)+32.44

version for use in raster calc is:
(20log10("West_Myara_rast_prox_2@1"))+(20log10 (6419.615)+32.44

I get "Expression invalid"

Comment: You have to add * for multiplication 20*log10

Comment: Did it you manage to make it work? Mark as solved if so.

Comment: hi again, yes I managed to work it all out. its fantastic :D now I gotta find a way of automating this entire process for 1000's of sites. thank you so much for all your help :D

Comment: Using python is quite easy to automate. Post a new question though if you have any trouble.